# Finding date range for current week, month and year

Tags: php

Suppose I have a date available with me:

```
2011-04-05 (i.e., 5th April, 2011)
```

I want to find date range for Current Week, Month and Year

```
Current Week:  3rd April to 9th April
Current Month: 1st April to 30 April
Current Year:  1st Jan to 31 Dec
```

I do understand that current year would be always 1st Jan to 31Dec, but what about current month and week, How can I find it?

**Edit:**

How can I find date, which is 10 days earlier or later from a given date.
Example:

Suppose today's date is 6th April, 2011
10 day's earlier: 28 March, 2011
10 day's later: 15 April, 2011

Any thoughts on this, guys?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can use [strtotime](http://tr.php.net/strtotime)

example :

```
    date('d.m.Y',strtotime('last day of this month')) 
date('d.m.Y',strtotime('last monday'))  // for first day of this week
```

Comment: $last_monday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$this_year-W$week_number")); 
        // print date of first day of week (MONDAY), week_number must be two digit and year must be 4 digit ISO 8601

Answer (score 33):

```
 function rangeMonth ($datestr) {
   date_default_timezone_set (date_default_timezone_get());
   $dt = strtotime ($datestr);
   return array (
     "start" => date ('Y-m-d', strtotime ('first day of this month', $dt)),
     "end" => date ('Y-m-d', strtotime ('last day of this month', $dt))
   );
 }

 function rangeWeek ($datestr) {
   date_default_timezone_set (date_default_timezone_get());
   $dt = strtotime ($datestr);
   return array (
     "start" => date ('N', $dt) == 1 ? date ('Y-m-d', $dt) : date ('Y-m-d', strtotime ('last monday', $dt)),
     "end" => date('N', $dt) == 7 ? date ('Y-m-d', $dt) : date ('Y-m-d', strtotime ('next sunday', $dt))
   );
 }

 print_r (rangeMonth('2011-4-5')); // format: YYYY-M-D
 print_r (rangeWeek('2011-4-5'));
```

output for `rangeMonth()`

```
Array
(
    [start] => 2011-04-01
    [end] => 2011-04-30
)
```

output for `rangeWeek()`

```
Array
(
    [start] => 2011-04-04
    [end] => 2011-04-08
)
```

Notice: functions like getdate(), date(), etc. throw **Warning** if default time zone is not set in php.ini.

Comment: Great Answer ! For the rangeWeek() function, we can modify it to be up to the second if timestamp is needed by doing : 
`function rangeWeek() {  
    $dt = time();  
    $res[0] = date('N', $dt)==1 ?  strtotime('today', $dt) : strtotime('last monday', $dt);  
    $res[1] = date('N', $dt)==7 ?  strtotime('today', $dt) : strtotime('next sunday', $dt);  
    return $res;   
    }  `

Answer (score 14):

This solution is simple, and it takes in consideration when the current day is Monday or Sunday.

NOTE: Using strtotime('last monday') may work if the day is other than Monday, otherwise it will return the previous Monday. Because of that we should use strtotime('last monday', strtotime('tomorrow')) and it will work for any day of the current week =)

Solution:

```
$monday = strtotime('last monday', strtotime('tomorrow'));
$sunday = strtotime('+6 days', $monday);
echo "<P>". date('d-M-Y', $monday) . " to " . date('d-M-Y', $sunday) . "</P>";
```

Answer (score 5):

The following code will give you the start and last date of a week:

```
   $today = getdate();
   print_r($today);
   echo "<br/>";

   $weekStartDate = $today['mday'] - $today['wday'];
   $weekEndDate = $today['mday'] - $today['wday']+6;
   echo "<br/>";
   echo "<br/>";
   echo "week start date:".$weekStartDate;
   echo "<br/>";
   echo "week end date:".$weekEndDate;
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: This is a nice idea in principle but in practice, the values returned aren't month-aware. By that I mean this code won't know how many days are in the current, previous and next months. Therefore if (and this will be a very common occurrence) the start or end day of the month is mid week then you're going to end up with negative values or dates that don't exist.

Comment: This is where `strtotime();` comes in really handy - see the solution by @Wh1T3h4Ck5

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [getdate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php) function, there are a few examples of how to use it on the manual page I linked.  I think it will return everything you're looking for,

Answer (score 4):

Working example it properly handles the Monday issue

```
<?php
$monday = strtotime("last monday");
$monday = date('w', $monday)==date('w') ? $monday+7*86400 : $monday;

$sunday = strtotime(date("Y-m-d",$monday)." +6 days");

$this_week_sd = date("Y-m-d",$monday);
$this_week_ed = date("Y-m-d",$sunday);

echo "Current week range from $this_week_sd to $this_week_ed ";
?>
```

Comment: A better way would be to use "strtotime('Monday this week');" that way you could easily get last weeks start/end dates as well, simply by changing "Monday this week" to "Monday last week".

Answer (score 0):

Today is Tuesday, August 27th 2019

This week is from Monday, August 26th 2019 to Sunday, September 1st 2019

```
php > $date = new DateTime('Sunday');
php > echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
2019-09-01 00:00:00

php > $date = new DateTime('Tuesday');
php > echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
2019-08-27 00:00:00

php > $date = new DateTime('Monday');
php > echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
2019-09-02 00:00:00

php > $date = new DateTime('Monday this week');
php > echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
2019-08-26 00:00:00
```