# Generate Friday Cutoff on PHP or MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding date range for current week, month and year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552862/finding-date-range-for-current-week-month-and-year)

Can Anyone help me on how could I generate Friday cutoff using PHP or MySQL. below is the sample date range

```
...
2012-10-06 to 2012-10-12
2012-10-13 to 2012-10-19
2012-10-20 to 2012-10-26
...
2012-12-22 to 2012-12-28
2012-12-29 to 2013-01-04
```

Comment: What *exactly* is it that you want? And what is the code that you currently have?

Comment: I want a code or just an idea on algorithm

Comment: friday cutoff means that the date range generated will start from Saturday and will end on Friday.. like on the above illustrations, start data is Saturday and end data is Friday.

Comment: What do you mean with `generating` the cutoff? To insert date ranges into database table with fields, e.g.: `week_number`, `start_date`, `end_date` or something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing the first saturday (the initial period) is easy to calculate the next friday (and looping the next saturday, next friday of second saturday....)

Check this code:

```
<?php
$saturday = '2012-10-06';
$next_friday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+6 days', strtotime($saturday)));

print "The next friday is $next_friday";
```

Comment: thanks, it helps me to do utility with the help of this code.. cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try this code ...

```
function getCurrentWeek($start , $end){
        $ts = strtotime($start);
        $te = strtotime($end);
        $days = round(abs($te-$ts)/86400);
        $range = '';
        $j = 0;
        // generate dates
        for ($i=0; $i<$days; $i++, $ts+=86400){
            $temp_date = date("Y-m-d", $ts);
            $d = (int) date('w',$ts);

            switch ($d) {

                case 5 :
                    if($j == 1)
                       $range .= $temp_date . "<br />" ;
                       $j = 0;
                    break; 

                case 6 :
                    $j = 1;
                    $range  .= $temp_date . " TO "  ;
                    break;


            }
        }
        return $range;
    }

    echo getCurrentWeek('2012-10-06','2013-01-06');
```

Ps) You need to input correct start and end date where you have a Friday at the end ... or you will have XXXX-XX-XX TO  EMPTY