# how can I get last week' date range in php?

Tags: php, date

how can I get last week' date range in php ?

see my codes bellow:

```
<?php 
    function get_last_week_dates(){
        // how can i get the date range last week ?
        // ex: today is 2014-2-8
        // the week date range of last week should be '2014-1-26 ~ 2014-2-1'
    }
?>
```

Comment: Where's your codes? Just function definintion, lol.

Comment: Duplicate post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798228/php-date-function-seven-days-previous

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552862/finding-date-range-for-current-week-month-and-year

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can use [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/strtotime)

```
$previous_week = strtotime("-1 week +1 day");

$start_week = strtotime("last sunday midnight",$previous_week);
$end_week = strtotime("next saturday",$start_week);

$start_week = date("Y-m-d",$start_week);
$end_week = date("Y-m-d",$end_week);

echo $start_week.' '.$end_week ;
```

**UPDATE**

Changed the code to handle sunday. If the current day is sunday then - 1 week will be previous sunday and again getting previous sunday for that will go the one week back.

```
$previous_week = strtotime("-1 week +1 day");
```

> In addition if we need to find the `current week` and `next week` date
> range we can do as

**Current week -**

```
$d = strtotime("today");
$start_week = strtotime("last sunday midnight",$d);
$end_week = strtotime("next saturday",$d);
$start = date("Y-m-d",$start_week); 
$end = date("Y-m-d",$end_week);
```

**Next Week -**

```
$d = strtotime("+1 week -1 day");
$start_week = strtotime("last sunday midnight",$d);
$end_week = strtotime("next saturday",$d);
$start = date("Y-m-d",$start_week); 
$end = date("Y-m-d",$end_week);
```

Comment: why did you add `+1 day`?

Comment: Say today is `sunday` so if you do `-1 week` then it becomes `previous sunday` so on that if you do `last sunday midnight` then it will go back to another `previous sunday` so adding `+1 day` so that if today is `sunday` I will get `monday` and on that date if I do `last sunday midnight` then I will exactly have the start date from last week sunday till next saturday

Comment: Problem still persists when you run this code on Saturday.

Comment: @wordpressure could you provide some details about the problem.

Comment: I copied your code to paste them into my code and it didn't work as expected. Now I found my problem requirement was a little bit different with what your solution addresses. your code is O.K. so far in my opinion. sorry to get you confused. :D

Comment: I know this is old but here's a much more succinct way of doing it (sorry for formatting - comments don't support it. I'll add an actual answer below).

`$startDate = date("m/d/y", strtotime(date("w") ? "2 sundays ago" : "last sunday"));
$endDate = date("m/d/y", strtotime("last saturday"));
echo $startDate . " - " . $endDate;`

Comment: I needed the time in addition to the date so I changed the first `$end_week` assignment to `$end_week = strtotime("next sunday", $start_week) - 1;` so that I get saturday at `23:59:59`

Answer (score 35):

Simply use

```
date("m/d/Y", strtotime("last week monday"));
date("m/d/Y", strtotime("last week sunday"));
```

It will give the date of Last week's Monday and Sunday.

Answer (score 2):

you need you use `strtotime` function for this

```
<center>
<?php
 function get_last_week_dates()
 {
        // how can i get the date range last week ?
        // ex: today is 2014-2-8
        // the week date range of last week should be '2014-1-26 ~ 2014-2-1'

        $startdate = "last monday";
        if (date('N') !== '1')
        { 
            // it's not Monday today
            $startdate .= " last week";
        }
        echo "<br />";
        $day = strtotime($startdate);
        echo date('r', $day);   
        echo "<br />";
        $sunday = strtotime('next monday', $day) - 1;
        echo date('r', $sunday);
    }
    get_last_week_dates();
?>
</center>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well just for the fun of trying to solve this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$firstDayOfLastWeek = mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")-date("w")-7);
$lastDayOfLastWeek = mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")-date("w")-1);
echo("Last week began on: ".date("d.m.Y",$firstDayOfLastWeek));
echo("<br>");
echo("Last week ended on: ".date("d.m.Y",$lastDayOfLastWeek));
```

Comment: I haven't tested your unexplained answer yet, but just from eyeballing it, I am concerned that this is ignoring the year component in the `mktime()` lines.  In other words, I am concerned that this will break when subtracting days moves the date to the previous year.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
$startWeek = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("Sunday Last Week"));
$endWeek = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("Sunday This Week"));
```

this would not work if ran on a Monday. It would get last Sunday (the day before) to the next Sunday. So using Abhik Chakraborty's method with the above:

```
$startTime = strtotime("last sunday midnight",$previous_week);
$endTime = strtotime("next sunday midnight",$startTime);
$startDate = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00',$startTime);
$endDate = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59',$endTime);
```

This will now give

```
start =  2014-08-10 00:00:00
endDate = 2014-08-17 23:59:59
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but here's a much more succinct way of doing it:

```
$startDate = date("m/d/y", strtotime(date("w") ? "2 sundays ago" : "last sunday"));
$endDate = date("m/d/y", strtotime("last saturday"));
echo $startDate . " - " . $endDate
```

Comment: For some reason this is returning a start date of Dec 29, 2018, which is a Saturday not a Sunday.

Comment: Maybe your php.ini doesn't have the right time zone or something. Paste the code into phptester.net and it shows Dec 30, 2018 which is a Sunday.

Comment: Interesting.  You're right.  Something is definitely different on my server.

Comment: I know you can experience issues when adding/subtracting seconds because of daylight saving time changes. But just running the code above should calculate correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This one will produce the proper result and handles the Monday issue

```
<?php
$monday = strtotime("last monday");
$monday = date('W', $monday)==date('W') ? $monday-7*86400 : $monday;

$sunday = strtotime(date("Y-m-d",$monday)." +6 days");
$this_week_sd = date("Y-m-d",$monday);
$this_week_ed = date("Y-m-d",$sunday);

echo "Last week range from $this_week_sd to $this_week_ed ";
?>
```

Comment: This fails if DST changes occur during the week.

Comment: This one also for some reason is returning a start date of Dec 29, 2018, which is a Saturday not a Sunday.

Answer (score 1):

Most of those other solutions offered were off by one day.
If you want Sunday to Saturday for last week, this is the way to do it.

```
$start = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("last sunday",strtotime("-1 week")));
$end = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("saturday",strtotime("-1 week")));

echo $start. " to ".$end;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Carbon**

```
$startOfTheWeek = Carbon::now()->subWeek(1)->startOfWeek();
$endOfTheWeek = Carbon::now()->subWeek(1)->endOfWeek();
```

From a specific date

```
$startOfTheWeek = Carbon::parse('2020-03-02')->subWeek(1)->startOfWeek();
$endOfTheWeek = Carbon::parse('2020-03-02')->subWeek(1)->endOfWeek();
```

Considering the week starts at Monday and ends at Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way.

First get the current timestamp and subtract the no.of days you want.

```
$curTime = time();
echo date("Y-m-d",$curTime);
echo "<br />";
echo date("Y-m-d",($curTime-(60*60*24*7)));
```

Comment: This may not always work: calculating diffs in this way may behave unexpectedly when DST starts or ends.

Answer (score 0):

```
$lastWeekStartTime = strtotime("last sunday",strtotime("-1 week"));
$lastWeekEndTime = strtotime("this sunday",strtotime("-1 week"));
$lastWeekStart = date("Y-m-d",$lastWeekStartTime);
$lastWeekEnd = date("Y-m-d",$lastWeekEndTime);
```

Comment: Close, but this returns two Sundays.  A week goes from Sunday to Saturday.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the last week start date and end date you can follow up this code for doing it so.

It works on all intervals to find the date interval.

```
$Current = Date('N');
$DaysToSunday = 7 - $Current;
$DaysFromMonday = $Current - 1;
$Sunday = Date('d/m/y', strtotime("+ {$DaysToSunday} Days"));
$Monday = Date('d/m/y', strtotime("- {$DaysFromMonday} Days"));
```

If so you need to change it with the `datatime()` you can perform this function.

```
$date = new DateTime();
$weekday = $date->format('w');
$diff = 7 + ($weekday == 0 ? 6 : $weekday - 1); // Monday=0, Sunday=6
$date->modify("-$diff day");
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . ' - ';
$date->modify('+6 day');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

> Using Functions:

If you want to find the last week range with the help of the functions you can preform like this.

**Function:**

```
// returns last week's range
function last_week_range($date) {
$ts = strtotime("$date - 7 days");
$start = (date('w', $ts) == 0) ? $ts : strtotime('last sunday', $ts);
return array(
      date('Y-m-d', $start),
      date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next saturday', $start))
);
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$today=date();
print_r(last_week_range($today));
```

All the above functions that has been given will return the last week range irrespective of the start day of the week..