# PHP - Last Saturday at 6pm

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have a query where I want to pass in two variables and I feel like I am almost there but need a bit of guidance.

I have a cron job set up to run at 6pm every Saturday that will select tickets for the last week.

Select tickets that are between 6pm last saturday and 5:59 today bearing in mind that this willl be run at 6pm every saturday.

I'm looking for help to create two variables.

- 6pm last Saturday
- 5:59pm today

Have looked at strtotime and date but can't see anything that would fit?

Comment: Sorry, what you need? A php code that will generate date?

Comment: I need to create a variable that always shows the previous saturday at 6pm

Comment: where are you stucked? in `cron` or in the `shell script` cron is going to use?

Comment: I need to create a variable that will show the value of the previous saturday at 6pm in a timestamp format

Comment: Check out **Datetime**

Comment: @user2701136 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644002/how-can-i-get-last-week-date-range-in-php

Answer (score 2):

Check [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
$time = strtotime("last Saturday 6 PM");
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);
```

Answer (score 0):

A mysql solution could be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tickets 
WHERE
    ticket_datetime BETWEEN 
                      DATE_SUB(CONCAT(DATE(NOW()),' 06:00:00'), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
                    AND 
                      CONCAT(DATE(NOW()),' 06:00:00')
```