# DateTime Get last week's date

Tags: php, function, date, datetime

I am trying to get the start & end date from last week and it fails to fetch data. Does work for other weeks so my guess is that it bugs due to the new year.
code:

```
function getStartAndEndDateOfWeek($week, $year) {
    $dto = new DateTime();
    $dto->setISODate($year, $week);
    $ret['week_start'] = $dto->format('Y-m-d');
    $dto->modify('+7 days');//1 day extra for BETWEEN query fix
    $ret['week_end'] = $dto->format('Y-m-d');
    return $ret;
}

//last week
        $lastWeek = (new DateTime('now'))->sub(new DateInterval('P7D'))->format('W');
        $year = (new DateTime('now'))->sub(new DateInterval('P7D'))->format('Y');
        $dateRange = getStartAndEndDateOfWeek($lastWeek, $year);
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644002/how-can-i-get-last-week-date-range-in-php